# Nameerror telebot is not define

Tags: python, nameerror

I' trying to make a bot telegram, but it throws Nameerror, exception on line 
`bot = telebot.TeleBot("754102396:AAEpwiIrfb57pZ-8EKsHj30C1LQoWCIpqbI")` it says `telebot is not define`

I tried uninstalling `telebot` and `PyTelegramBotAPI` then installing `PyTelegramBotAPI==2.2.3` via `pip`, but only get worse. So I undo the changes.

Here is the code, I hope you can help me:

```
from telebot import TeleBot


bot = telebot.TeleBot("754102396:AAEpwiIrfb57pZ-8EKsHj30C1LQoWCIpqbI")

@bot.message_handler(commands = ["help", "start"])
def enviar_mensaje(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Hola, soy un bot")

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def message(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, message.text)

bot.polling()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line to,

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot("754102396:AAEpwiIrfb57pZ-8EKsHj30C1LQoWCIpqbI")
```

to

```
bot = TeleBot("754102396:AAEpwiIrfb57pZ-8EKsHj30C1LQoWCIpqbI")
```

Comment: Well it solves the exception, but i get more errors haha. Thanks.

Comment: If it solve your `NameError` issue accept the answer. And you can ask another question for new errors!

Comment: There you have, congratulations